# Passing .net core model data to external javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET Core 2 Razor view with the underlying model inside  a *.cshtml.cs file. Let's say I have a string like this:

```
public string myVar = "hello world";
```

How can I access this variable (data) inside my external JavaScript file?

I need this for example in the following case. I'm using the jVectorMap jquery library. There I can select multiple regions of the map. I have to save the selected regions (let's say in an array of unique ids) so that I can pre-populate the map with the selected regions, if the user loads the special page with the map inside. And the data (selected regions) can be different do different users. So I have to store the data for each user and the have to load the data. jVectorMap has an API function which allows to pre-populate the map with some data.

But how can I access my saved variable / data inside the external javascript file?

**EDIT:**
I added an example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QV4Fi1

Comment: In my project I used cookies to pass data between them. Or you can set a hidden div with all data you what to read from JS

Comment: Add `@inject IJsonHelper Json;` in your view, and then inside your script - `var value = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.myVar))` (assumes your scripts is not in an external js file)

Comment: @StephenMuecke and if my script is an external js file? How can do this then?

Comment: You need to do it in the main view (i.e. assign it as a global variable) and access `value` in the external file. Alternatively you could assign it to an element as a `data` attribute -for example `<button data-value="@Model.myVar" ... >` and in the js file `$('button').click(function() { var value = $(this).data('value');` .... `

Comment: ok i understand, but i have the data not in the main view. i want to access the variable from the the model class.

Comment: i added an example

Comment: @AlexG. No doubt because the goal posts kept moving. The downvote was on the same day the OP finally added the example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get *C#/Razor* values as a string easily enough.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = parseInt('@Model.i');
</script>
```

Or you can try with below given options.

**Option 1:**

```
var myVar = '@Model.MyVar';
var name = '@Model.Name';
```

**Option 2:**

```
var myVar ='@Html.Raw(Model.MyVar)';
var name = '@Html.Raw(Model.Name)';
```

Comment: And „i“ is my Variable inside my c# Code like my „myVar“ in my example right? I‘ll test it

Comment: tried it and did not work for me. it only prints out "@i". Could you provide a working example?

Comment: thanks. i tried it again but anyway no change. Does this only works if i use the javascript code directly inside my view inside the <script>-Tags? If i do it this way your solution works very well, but not if i have my code inside a external js file which to which i reference via the <script>-Tag. Any solution for this? i added an example in my question.

Comment: @Opa114 you can extract value in inline script and pass it in your external js file's function.

Comment: oh yeah this works but in this case isn't it better to let the whole javascript stuff inline inside the view? And another clean and simple solution to access the data from a model in an external javascript file is not possible or?

Comment: or did it work like inline if i put the JavaScript code inside a partial view and not into a js file?

Comment: @lazydeveloper killed it thanks for the concise answer

Comment: Be careful with this for production sites. You will have to support 'unsafe-inline' javascript, which isn't very OWASP friendly. A better alternative is mentioned by LP13.

Answer (score 9):

**Option1**

**Model**

```
public class MyModel
{
   public string MyProperty {get;set;}
}
```

**cshtml**

```
@model WebAppp.MyModel

@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.MyProperty)
```

**javascript**

```
  $("#MyProperty").val();
```

**Option 2**
 In controller you can store in ViewData or ViewBag

```
 ViewBag["MyPropertyValue"]  ="something";
```

in cshml ( i havent tried but should work)

```
@Html.Hidden("MyProperty",ViewData["MyPropertyValue"],new { @class = "someclass" })
```

**javascript**

```
  $("#MyProperty").val();
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example with an strong typed ViewModel and an **C#-list** which will be serialized into an js-array.

**The ViewModel:**

```
namespace ProjectName.ViewModels
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        // List
        public List<string> MyList { get; set; }

        // a simple variable
        public string MyVar{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the view use the following code to pass the list of your C#-ViewModel to an JavaScript array.

**The View (*.cshtml):**

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myArray = JSON.parse('@Json.Serialize(@Model.MyList)');
    var myVar = '@Model.MyVar';
</script>
```

Instead of the list you can also use an object.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found much easier solution for parsing arrays/lists.
Consindering you have this view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // List
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; }

    // a simple variable
    public string MyVar{ get; set; }
}
```

You can simply use this:

```
<script>
    var myList = @Json.Serialize(Model.MyList);
</script>
```

The same syntax can be used for the single object.

Comment: Thank you. After few hours i found this working code.